# Pythonic solution to cryptographic agility that avoids violating Liskov's substitution principle

Tags: python, oop, encryption

I need to write a set of wrappers in python around symmetric ciphers (AES,DES, etc) in various modes of operation that allow for [crypto agility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321570.aspx). Specifically, the code that is calling the wrappers needs to need no knowledge for what actually is protecting the data so it can be changed out dynamically

Basically the following  should hold ( whether these are methods on an object, separate functions, or something else)

```js
foo = MagicalEncryptor()
foo.ciphertext = foo.encrypt(data)
key = foo.key 
bar = MagicalEncryptor()
bar.key = key 
data = bar.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

The problem is that depending on the mode used, the resulting ciphertext will be different. It may be (MODE_CBC,IV,ciphertext) for CBC or (MODE_GCM,IV,ciphertext,mac) for GCM mode.

This very clearly violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) because it makes the argument to decrypt covariant. If the caller is holding an instance of the generic `magicalEncryptor` interface that happens to be for GCM mode, it cannot hand it an instance of ECB mode.

What's a good pythonic solution to this? (Or is the answer simply not to care?) For what I specifically need to do, it ought to work in both 2.7 and 3.0, but I'm interested in solutions for either.

Also, key must have a short representation as a bitstream (probably 128 or 256 bits max). This is meant to be used in hybrid encryption schemes, where, for example, one might send (RSA_ENC(PublicKey,symetric_key_as_message)||AES(symetric_key_as_message,actual_message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Kirk, but peeling off at the last minute, let the polymorphic key take care of choosing the right kind of decryptor:

```
foo = MagicalEncryptor()
foo.ciphertext = foo.encrypt(data)
key = foo.key 

bar = key.decryptor()
data = bar.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

It can create the appropriate decryptor and pass itself in. Or whatever: the protocol between the key and the creation of decryptors is private.

I might even rearrange things like this:

```
key = createMagicalKey()

foo = key.encryptor()
ciphertext = foo.encrypt(data)

bar = key.decryptor()
data = bar.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

And of course then it's only a simple step to:

```
key = createMagicalKey()

ciphertext = key.encrypt(data)

data = key.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Comment: A decent solution. Unfortunately, as I just clarified above, the keys basically must have reasonably short bitstream representations as they need to be encrypted themselves with the likes of RSA\DSA\ far more exotic things. Probably 128 or 256 bits at most.

Comment: I don't believe my suggestion is incompatible with short bitstream representations; it's an API design, not a protocol format. I'm not suggesting you have to send the bytecodes of the magical key or anything - just some sort of tag which says what sort of magical key it is. Provided the receiver knows the same set of tags as you, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Method one: strongly type the encrypted data:

```
class GCMData(object):
    def __init__(self, data): self.data = data

    def __str__(self): return self.data
    __repr__ = __str__


class MagicalGCMEncryptor(object):
    def encrypt(self, data):
        return GCMData(self._encrypt(data))

    def decrypt(self, dataobj):
        if not isinstance(dataobj, GCMData):
            raise ValueError('Only decrypts GCM data')
```

Method two: invert flow control. Don't make classes that encrypt data. Make data objects that store encrypted data:

```
class GCMEncryptedData(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = [... do something with data]

    def __str__(self): return self.data
    __repr__ = __str__

    def decrypt(self):
        return [... do something with self.data]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that inverting the flow control solves the problem. You still need to take care to pass the right kind of key around.

Comment: Solution 1 seems to just make the liskov substitution problem explicit. MagicalGCMEncryptor is not a subclass of MagicalEncryptor.

Solution 2 is an avenue, but as @TomAnderson says it causes some issues with keys. Moreover, it makes interop with other languages hard and 3) unserializing the data is an interesting problem.We certainly can't use pickle since if we trusted the data in the first place, encrypting it would be moot.

Answer (score 0):

"This very clearly violates the Liskov substitution principle because it makes the argument to decrypt covariant. If the caller is holding an instance of the generic magicalEncryptor interface that happens to be for GCM mode, it cannot hand it an instance of ECB mode."

Nor should it. Encryption cannot be a mode-independent black-box. Yes, you can swap TDES with AES-256 without changing a lot of higher level logic, but that is not true for changing encryption *modes*. Think of a mode as a protocol, and an algorithm as an engine. A protocol is complicated, as it requires its own special error reporting, failure mechanism, initialization procedures, associated data, state information, etc. By contrast, swapping the algorithm engine is easy.

For example, when using GCM, you need to take care that you do not encrypt too many messages and that you rotate your keys more quickly in order to maintain the cryptographic strength of your mac. That is true whether it is TDES-GCM or AES-256-GCM. That means you should keep track of how many messages have been encrypted -- even if this is a ballpark estimate such as "rekey every X days when using mode Y" (although you really care about the quantity of data processed.)

You don't have these concerns (at a practical level) with ECB, but you have a whole different set (of much more difficult) concerns regarding information leakage.

CBC mode has its own usage pitfalls, particularly if you are also using CBC-MAC. Depending on the authentication method used, you need to be careful about reporting error messages when the MAC fails -- in some cases, the failure of the MAC should result in destruction of the key (e.g. session keys), but in other cases failure of the MAC should only result in resetting the protocol run (keeping your authentication key sets). Or perhaps you *can* replay the message -- it depends on how you are building your protocol and what algorithms you are using.

If you are using a tweak encryption mode for stored data, you care about where the data resides on disk, and you will re-use the same tweak key and positional value if you are overwriting a block in place. But you would never reuse a message counter with the same session key if you were encrypting a channel. The encryption modes suitable for encrypting data-in-place have no overlap with the encryption modes suitable for encrypting a channel. They are not swappable with each other.

All of that violates the Liskov substitution principle unless you attempt to implement a generic "security" object that can specialize to every conceivable data protection protocol.

Moreover you would *never* *ever* use the same key in two different modes or two different algorithm engines.

So why design the code in a such a way that allows an instance of a key object to be specialized to more than one algorithm implementation? Now your security team is going to have go back over your code and ensure that this generality isn't opening any holes for an attacker to get your application to abuse a key by using it in the wrong way. You will need to go back and ensure that when you instantiate your key, you fully specify the mode and algorithm with which it will be used in the key's constructor, which goes back to the issue of key length. Any subsequent attempts to use the key in a with a different algorithm or mode with which it was instantiated should result in an critical error.

But in that case, what does "algorithm agility" mean if users or the application needs to create new keys and/or rekey existing data in place each time the underlying system adopts a new algorithm?